# The query does not show me the pages of the books or the titles

Tags: xquery

I have been trying to query for a while and I am not able. The examples you have given me are very simple. Title, first author and pages of the borrowed books. that's the exercise. This is what I have tried but I did not get anything back.

This is my query

```
  let $b := //biblioteca
    for $c in $b/prestamos/entrada/titulo
    for $d in $b/libros/libro[/titulo=$c]
    return $c and $d/paginas and $d/autor
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Fichero: libros.xml -->
<biblioteca>
 <libros>
  <libro publicacion="2003" edicion="2">
    <titulo>Learning XML</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Ray</apellido>
      <nombre>Erik T.</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>416</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2003" edicion="2">
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Harold</apellido>
      <nombre>Elliot Rusty</nombre>
    </autor>
    <autor>
    <apellido>Means</apellido>
      <nombre>W. Scott</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>832</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2002">
    <titulo>XML Schema</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>van der Vlist</apellido>
      <nombre>Eric</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>400</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2002">
    <titulo>XPath Essentials</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Watt</apellido>
      <nombre>Adrew</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>Wiley</editorial>
    <paginas>516</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2005">
    <titulo> Beginning XSLT 2.0: Form Novice to Professional</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Tennison</apellido>
      <nombre>Jeni</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>Apress</editorial>
    <paginas>797</paginas>
  </libro>
  <libro publicacion="2007">
    <titulo> XQuery</titulo>
    <autor>
      <apellido>Walmsley</apellido>
      <nombre>Priscilla</nombre>
    </autor>
    <editorial>O'Reilly</editorial>
    <paginas>491</paginas>
  </libro>
 </libros>

<!-- Tabla prestamos -->
 <prestamos>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-05-02</inicio>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Pepito</nombre>
        <apellidos>Grillo</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>972987654</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XML Imprescindible</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-02-12</inicio>
      <devolucion>2011-02-16</devolucion>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Jose</nombre>
        <apellidos>GutiÃ©rrez GonzÃ¡lez</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>919485432</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
  <entrada>
    <titulo>XPath Essentials</titulo>
    <prestamo>
      <inicio>2011-02-23</inicio>
      <devolucion>2011-03-10</devolucion>
      <lector>
        <nombre>Pepito</nombre>
        <apellidos>Grillo</apellidos>
        <direccion>Rue Percebe, 13</direccion>
        <telefono>972987654</telefono>
      </lector>
    </prestamo>
  </entrada>
 </prestamos>
</biblioteca>
```

I am working in java with a DB and I need to create a script with this query but the examples I have from the teacher are very basic and I cannot find the error I made when doing the query. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the predicate you probably want `$b/libros/libro[titulo=$c]` and not `$b/libros/libro[/titulo=$c]`, as `/titulo` selects a `titulo` root element while `titulo` selects a `titulo` child of the `libro` element the predicate is used on.

The operator `and` is a boolean operator so I doubt you want to use that in the `return` clause. You have not shown which result you want, the comma operator `($c, $d/paginas, $d/autor)` is more likely to return a meaningful result.